# Converting a video stream from a camera to IP

Tags: wireless-networking, video, video-streaming, ipad

I have a standard camera providing a normal video stream via video cabel to a tv system.

I would now like to be able to intercept this video stream to either

- a hardware device to broadcast directly via WiFi to be viewed in realtime on an ipad
- a software setup the means I can record the stream and then rebroadcast via wifi to an ipad.

Does anyone know what I'm looking for how I'd go about it?